# Using a Variable to Point to a Specific Character in a String

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, nasm

I am working on a program where I need to be able change characters at specific places within a string as the user moves through it, and I'd like to use a variable to store the user's position within the string.

While working on other parts of the program, I temporarily used the code below, where buffer is my string:

```
mov eax, buffer
mov byte [eax + 14], '@'
```

In the finished program, I'd like to use something like:

```
mov byte [eax + position], '@'
```

However, when I use the line above, with position set to 14, I get a segmentation fault.  How can I use a variable to point to a specific spot in the string?

EDIT: The position variable is set as follows:

```
segment .data
position db 14
```

Comment: What is `position`, and how are you setting it to 14? Is it a label, a constant, a register?

Comment: I set `position` under `segment .data` as `position db 14`.  That was a good question, I added it to my main post.

Comment: `[eax + position]` is eax plus address of position. You want `[eax + [position]]` and we have no such instruction. Do something like `mov ecx, [position]` Make position dd not db! Then `[eax + ecx]` should work.

Comment: @FrankKotler That worked perfectly! Thank you! If you wish to post it as an official answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... [eax + position] is eax plus address of position. You want [eax + [position]] and we have no such instruction. Do something like mov ecx, [position] Make position dd not db! Then [eax + ecx] should work.